# Specific font size for specific data values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having some colour issues... I'm using a template i found online and i'm struggling to apply colour to the circles without hardcoding them...

Basically (and sorry for coding my data, rather than using a csv file), i'm looking to apply a certain colour to data elements April, June and October. Then a separate colour for the data elements within them? So the children elements for April will be blue, July's will be red and Octobers will be green.

Also, i'd like the text to get smaller for each node. So rather than have a function that won't show the text below a certain value, i'd like the text to get smaller, then have a function that won't show the text below a value like 7000, if you get what i mean?

Once again, i apologise for the way i've inputted my data.

(i've only included the javascript)

Cheers

***EDIT!
I've found a way to append specific colour to the children of each season. It may be inefficient, but it works (and it's not hardcoded!). But i am still struggling to change text size based on the data values.***

```
  var data = {
  "name": "The World",
  "children": [{
      "name": "April",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Bolivia",
        "value": 3613,
      }, {
        "name": "Brazil",
        "value": 1115167,
      }, {
        "name": "Peru",
        "value": 81082,
      }, {
        "name": "Angola",
        "value": 1282,
      }, {
        "name": "Burndi",
        "value": 10064,
      }, {
        "name": "Madagascar",
        "value": 16658,
      }, {
        "name": "Malawi",
        "value": 1338,
      }, {
        "name": "Rwanda",
        "value": 8734,
      }, {
        "name": "Zimbabwe",
        "value": 2191,
      }, {
        "name": "Papa New Guinea",
        "value": 28735,
      }, {
        "name": "Timor-Leste",
        "value": 857,
      }]
    }, {
    "name": "July",
    "children": [{
        "name": "Cuba",
        "value": 5716,
      }, {
        "name": "Dominican Rebpublic",
        "value": 14313,
      }, {
        "name": "Haiti",
        "value": 10951,
      }, {
        "name": "Tanzania",
        "value": 22378,
      }, {
        "name": "Zambia",
        "value": 1218,
      }, {
        "name": "Philippines",
        "value": 14327,
      }]
    }, {
      "name": "October",
      "children": [{
        "name": "Colombia",
        "value": 331738,
      }, {
        "name": "Costa Rica",
        "value": 57043,
      }, {
        "name": "El Salvador",
        "value": 45573,
      }, {
        "name": "Guatemala",
        "value": 109461,
      }, {
        "name": "Honduras",
        "value": 98918,
      }, {
        "name": "Mexico",
        "value": 122305,
      }, {
        "name": "Nicaragua",
        "value": 39943,
      }, {
        "name": "Panama",
        "value": 4426,
      }, {
        "name": "Cameroon",
        "value": 22075,
      }, {
        "name": "Central Africa",
        "value": 2987,
      }, {
        "name": "Congo, Dem, Rep. of",
        "value": 16727,
      }, {
        "name": "Côte d'ivoire",
        "value": 74893,
      }, {
        "name": "Ethiopia",
        "value": 133963,
      }, {
        "name": "Ghana",
        "value": 1171,
      }, {
        "name": "Guinea",
        "value": 7604,
      }, {
        "name": "Kenya",
        "value": 27668,
      }, {
        "name": "Nigeria",
        "value": 1279,
      }, {
        "name": "Sierra Leone",
        "value": 1371,
      }, {
        "name": "Togo",
        "value": 4533,
      }, {
        "name": "Uganda",
        "value": 88946,
      }, {
        "name": "Laos",
        "value": 7987,
      }, {
        "name": "India",
        "value": 12500,
      }, {
        "name": "Sri Lanka",
        "value": 1151,
      }, {
        "name": "Thailand",
        "value": 27064,
      }, {
        "name": "Vietnam",
        "value": 408979,
      }, {
        "name": "Yemen",
        "value": 3068
      }]
    }]
    };

    var packLayout = d3.pack()
      .size([700, 700]);

    var rootNode = d3.hierarchy(data)

    rootNode.sum(function(d) {
      return d.value;
    });

    packLayout(rootNode);

    const seasons = ["April", "July", "October"];

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(seasons)
      .range(["#A8A7A7"]);

    const april = ["Bolivia","Brazil","Peru","Angola","Burndi","Madagascar",
    "Malawi","Rwanda","Zimbabwe","Papa New Guinea","Timor-Leste"];

    var color1 = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(april)
      .range(["#2F9599"]);

    const july = ["Cuba","Dominican Rebpublic","Haiti","Tanzania","Zambia",
    "Philippines"];

    var color2 = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(july)
      .range(["#E8175D"]);

      const october = ["Colombia","Costa Rica","El Salvador","Guatemala",
      "Honduras","Mexico","Nicaragua","Panama","Cameroon","Central Africa",
      "Congo, Dem, Rep. of","Côte d'ivoire","Ethiopia","Ghana","Guinea",
      "Kenya","Nigeria","Sierra Leone","Togo","Uganda","Laos","India",
      "Sri Lanka","Thailand","Vietnam","Yemen"];

      var color3 = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(october)
        .range(["#CC527A"]);

    var nodes = d3.select('svg g')
      .selectAll('g')
      .data(rootNode.descendants())
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .attr('transform', function(d) {return 'translate(' + [d.x, d.y] + ')'})

    nodes
      .append('circle')
      .attr('r', function(d) { return d.r; })
      .attr("fill", function(d){
        var result = null;

        if (seasons.indexOf(d.data.name) >= 0) {
          result = color(d.data.name);
        } else if (april.indexOf(d.data.name) >= 0){
          result = color1(d.data.name);
        } else if (july.indexOf(d.data.name) >= 0){
          result = color2(d.data.name);
        } else if (october.indexOf(d.data.name) >= 0){
          result = color3(d.data.name);
        } else {
          result = "white"
        }

          return result;
        });

    nodes
      .append('text')
      .attr('dy', 4)
      .text(function(d) { if(d.data.value > 29000)
        return d.children === undefined ? d.data.name : '';
      })
```

Comment: You can set a class attribute on every circle, with the name of the month -- then just use css styling to map the fill colors to the class the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you are appending your text add a `font-size` style and have it be a function return.

```js
nodes.append('text')
  .attr('dy', 4)
  .text(function(d) { if(d.data.value > 29000)
    return d.children === undefined ? d.data.name : '';
  })
  .style("font-size", function(d){
    return d * 5 + "px";
  })
```

Or however your want the data to change the sizing of your text.